# jquery selector to get all select dropdowns with a particular value selected

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

How do I select all the select boxes using a jQuery selector where value selected is "A1"?

Sample select box:

```
<select name="accesslevel">
<option value="A1">A1 Access</option>
<option value="A2">A2 Access</option>
</select>
```

I have to use the selector to do the following thing:

```
.parent().nextAll('td[id^="A1Access"]').show();
.parent().nextAll('td[id^="A2Access"]').hide();
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try :

```
$('select option[value="A1"]:selected')
```

Comment: This will return the option itself, not the select box.

Comment: @DSKVR good point, simple enough to `.parent('select')` from here though.  Or just `.parent()`.

Comment: I was just giving selector, now with it he can do whatever he wanted to do via the selector

Comment: I think dsnettleton 's answer is better than this one

Answer (score 51):

As mentioned before, Prakash's solution is the closest, but it selects the option value rather than the select box itself. This can be fixed with the :has selector.

```
$('select:has(option[value="A1"]:selected)')
```

Comment: This selector has incredable poor performance in IE Edge (and maybe other ie as well).
Use this instead: $('option:selected').filter('[value="A1"]').parent();

Comment: you can also do $('select').has('option[value="A1"]:selected')

Answer (score 3):

```
$('select').filter(
function(){   
   if($(this).val()=="A1")
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
)
```

you can add your function after this like

```
$('select').filter(
function(){   
   if($(this).val()=="A1")
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
).parent().nextAll('td[id^="A1Access"]').show();
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's something like your original spec, but just modified a bit to work with my selectors.

```
$('.container').find('option[value=A1]').filter(':selected').parent('select').show();
```

And here it is Simplified:

```
$('option[value=A1]:selected').parent('select');
```

Answer (score 0):

For simply selecting option in all html body

```
alert($('option[value=A1]').html());
```

For `select`

```
alert($('select[name=accesslevel]').find('option[value=A1]').html());
```

But alert will work with only one element.

For select you have

```
$('option[value=A1]').parent().remove();
```

It will select the parent and remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Make an id like this..

```
<select name="accesslevel" id="myselector">
<option value="A1">A1 Access</option>
<option value="A2">A2 Access</option>
</select>
```

Now select it with that id.

```
$("select#myselector option:selected").each(function () 
{
     alert($(this).text() + " ");
});
```